# printing the checksum of a txt file without printing the file path

Tags: c, linux, string, parsing, tokenize

I want to compute the checksum of a txt file using C in mac, thus I wrote a simple program as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];
    if(!(in = popen("shasum ritesh_file_test.txt", "r")))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
    {
        cout << buff;
    }

    printf ("checksum = %s",buff);
    pclose(in);
    return 0;
```

it prints the checksum of txt file , but also it prints the path of file. as

> 30b574b4ddbc681d9e5e6492ae82b32a7923e02e  ritesh_file_test.txt

How do I get rid of this path and only access the checksum value?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't mix `cout` and `printf`; please stick to one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The output format of `shasum` is of form

```
 <HASH> <Filename>
```

so, the hash value and the file name are separated by a space. One possible way, to separate the hash from the complete outpuy, is to *tokenize* `buff` before printing.

You can make use of  [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)  and use space () as delimiter to take out only the checksum value.

That said, in `C`, you don't include `#include <iostream>`, don't use `using namespace std;` and don't write `cout`. Moreover, use a `C` compiler to compile `C` code.

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions:

1. Since you are using a shell, `shasum ritesh_file_test.txt | awk '{ print $1; }'` might work.
2. Since you are using C++:

   ```
   std::string checksum(buff);
   checksum = checksum.substr(0, checksum.find(' ') -1 );
   ```
3. Or even, since a hash is always 40 bytes:

   ```
   std::string checksum(buff, 40);
   ```

I leave error checking as an exercise for you!